Tabular JS how to get pagination click from AJAX/FETCH
I would like to know how to get the current filters and the clicked page when I click on the pagination area, so that they can be sent as "params" via AJAX?
When I filter my options, it correctly generates an AJAX fetch with the data (but the current page is missing).
However, when I click on the pagination, no fetch is triggered, and I can't figure out where the issue comes from.
Thank you for your valuable help.
Doc: https://tabulator.info/examples/4.1#pagination
I would like to get the filters + the clicked page via fetch when I click on either the pagination or the filters.
This is my code:
let table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height:"100%",
    placeholder:"No Datas",
    layout:"fitColumns",
    sortMode:"remote",
    filterMode:"remote",
    headerFilterLiveFilterDelay:600,
    pagination:"remote",
    ajaxURL:"http://127.0.0.1:5500/file.json",
    ajaxParams:{token:"ABC123"},
    ajaxConfig:"GET",
    ajaxContentType:"json",
    persistence:false,
    columnDefaults:{
        tooltip:true,
    },
    paginationSize:5,
    paginationButtonCount:4,
    paginationSizeSelector:[5,10,20,50,100,200],
    rowHeader:{headerSort:false, resizable: false, frozen:true, headerHozAlign:"center", hozAlign:"center", formatter:"rowSelection", titleFormatter:"rowSelection", cellClick:function(e, cell){
      cell.getRow().toggleSelect();
    }},
    paginationCounter:function(pageSize, currentRow, currentPage, totalRows, totalPages){
        //console.log(pageSize, currentRow, currentPage, totalRows, totalPages)
    },
    ajaxURLGenerator:function(url, config, params){
        return url + "?params=" + encodeURI(JSON.stringify(params));
    },
    movableColumns:false,
    movableRows: false,
    columns:[
        {title:"id", field:"id", width:150, headerFilter:"input"},
        {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150, headerFilter:"input"},
        {title:"Progress", field:"progress", sorter:"number", hozAlign:"left", formatter:"progress", editable:true, headerSort:true, headerFilter:"input"},
        {title:"Couleurs", field:"col", headerFilter:"input"},
        {title:"Dates", field:"dob", headerFilter:"input"}
    ],
    printAsHtml:true,
    printHeader:"<h1>Example Table Header<h1>",
    printFooter:"<h2>Example Table Footer<h2>",
    langs:{
        "fr":{
            "pagination":{
                "first":"Premier",
                "first_title":"Première Page",
                "last":"Dernier",
                "last_title":"Dernière Page",
                "prev":"Précédent",
                "prev_title":"Page Précédente",
                "next":"Suivant",
                "next_title":"Page Suivante",
                "all":"Toute",
                "page_size":"Affichage",
            },
        }
    }
});

/**
 * Trigger Actions Table
 */
document.getElementById("print-table").addEventListener("click", function(){
    table.print(false, true);
});

/**
 * Initialize table after is fully loaded
 */
table.on("tableBuilt", () => {
    table.setLocale("fr");
      //  console.log(table.getPage());
});

Use ajax generator for send pagination.. or detect click + filters nothing see
